# Filter dataframe in python with multiple equations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, filtering

I have dataframe **df** that looks like this

```
    Lvl    Distance    iMap     Grp
0   37     63          A3       1
1   37     59          A9       1
2   37     54          A3       2
3   37     48          A4       2
...
190 37     27          A3       1
191 37     20          A3       4
```

I have 2 filters that I am trying to combine with "OR"

The first is `m1`

```
m1 = df[(df["Distance"]<55)].groupby('Grp').cumcount().eq(0)
```

you notice that `m1` index starts with 2 (not 0)

```
>>> m1
2      True
3      False
4      False
       ...
187    True
188    False
189    False
190    False
191    False
```

also the 2nd filter

```
m2 = df['Distance'].gt(55)
```

you notice that `m2` index starts with 0

```
>>> m2
0      True
1      True
2      False
3      False
4      False
       ...
187    False
188    False
189    False
190    False
191    False
```

When I try to combine both filters

```
df[m1 | m2]
```

and results

```
    Lvl    Distance    iMap     Grp
2   37     54          A3       2
19  37     41          A4       3
74  37     36          A3       1
187 37     29          A3       4
```

you can see that the first 2 records were not selected although their value is True in `m2`

but that value does not exist in `m1`

any idea how to fix this? so if any index is True it shows

Comment: It would be helpful if you could check and report the output of `m1 | m2`. And filtering is usually done like `df.loc[m1 | m2]` but it is unlikely to cause this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, `m1` construction is incomplete. You need to create a mask that has the same length as `df`. To do that, one method is, via the `isin()` method, check if the indexes of the rows flagged as True in `m1` exist in `df.index`. That way, you can make the True values in `m1` correspond to `df.index`.

```py
# first create groups as before
m1 = df[df['Distance']<55].groupby('Grp').cumcount().eq(0)
# filter for the index of the values flagged True in `m1` and 
# flag the rows of these indexes as True
m1 = df.index.isin(m1.index[m1])

# m2 construction as before
m2 = df['Distance'].gt(55)

# filter
df[m1|m2]
```

For the given input, the above code produces the following dataframe.
[image: res]

Answer (score 0):

You can [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `m1` to make it conform to `df`, like so

```
m1 = df[(df["Distance"]<55)].groupby('Grp').cumcount().eq(0).reindex(df.index, fill_values=False)
```